# Would like to confirm answer (regarding sets)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

As you might know from my precious questions, I am pretty weak with quantifiers.

[image]

Below is my solution to the stated problem, if incorrect, could someone explain why?

My attempted solution:

```
let P(x) be sin{x} = 0 and Q(x) be cos{x} = 0 and S be the set of integer multiples of pi
```

Clearly, for every x is S, P(x) is true, but Q(x) is false, thus the hypothesis is correct (that for every x is S, P(x) is true), but the conclusion is false (since no x in S makes Q(x) true). Thus the statement is false

Comment: The statement in part (a) is false rather than true, so try coming up with a counterexample. Your method in (b) looks fine: the converse is "If $\exists x\in\emptyset$, $Q(x)$, then $\forall x\in\emptyset$, $P(x) \implies Q(x)$." This can be seen to be a true statement either because the conclusion is vacuously true (as you point out) or because the hypothesis is vacuously false.

Comment: @GregMartin is this because the statement in part a is "too demanding"

Comment: This is strange, to me this statement seems to be true ... think about it: if P(x) implies Q(x) ... then whatever element that makes p(x) true will also make Q(x) true ... correct?

Comment: If there is an element that makes $P(x)$ true, then yes, then that element would also make $Q(x)$ true. But the hypothesis does not assert that there exists an element that makes $P(x)$ true!